# AEM Communities sites creation

Tags: aem

I'm trying to understand how is working aem community creation. I read in the documentation, but can get clear view what is going on. I have created a custom template in the community and then order some of the community features like(blog, group). I just wanna know how aem decides where is the position of the exact hbs component. Can someone give me some help with that.

Regards

Comment: Hey, i also wondering like how AEM Communities will work, and it's document doesn't answer all our questions, i need to add more feature to RTE of AEM Blog component. can anyone help us. Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific? There is a lot of info on https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/communities/getting-started.html so not sure which part is causing issues for you.

Comment: while adding an new article in AEM Blog component, can we add images from AEM DAM ? i can see a Image browser which takes images from our local system/external URL's not DAM.  (for quick review http://localhost:4502/content/community-components/en/journal.html)